# Why was Yoshimi killed?

Tags: from-the-new-world

In the second part of the series after the first time skip, Saki learns that she did have a sister called Yoshimi. According to the comments made by her mother, Yoshimi was killed by an Impure Cat.

Yoshimi showed signs of having gained her powers early but didn't seem controlled because of how her name looked in the mirror Saki found. Considering that she didn't look all that much older to Saki,

- Was Yoshimi really that much of a threat to have developed her powers so early that she had to die?
- Isn't the purpose of the Unified Class to help children and teenagers control their powers?
- Why couldn't Yoshimi just be a child prodigy who could one day take Shisei Kaburagi place?

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer in the book. She had an eyesight problem (astigmatism + short-sightedness) that was misinterpreted as a defect of her cantus. Her eyesight problem is the reason her name in the mirror looked the way it did.

Answer (score 0):

In the anime, any child who wasn't able to consciously control their abilities was considered a threat because their unconscious mind might accidentally create a dangerous situation for the entire community. For example, warping reality as an instinctive defence mechanism, or killing someone who might threaten them even if the child didn't want it to happen.

There were other factors in the books, but these may not be canon to the anime.

Answer (score -1):

I wondered the same thing. Is it possible that perhaps she never graduated elementary?

Saki's mother was very excited when Saki's spirit came to her finally. Throwing herself into her, it could be from feeling another failure for her last chance as a mother.

Or perhaps she moved up quickly but then became stuck in a rut like Shun. Maybe she was a student much like their 5th partner who didn't last long.

Her inability to gain any traction on her powers may have been looked down on. Maybe it depressed her sister and had an opportunity to bring rise to a demon. Perhaps the child seemed too problematic and posed a threat to become the next demon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please support it by including links to back it up. Please see [How to write a good answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for ideas on how to improve your answer.